# Error writing shell script in python for mongodb In case of userid call

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo-3.x

```
cursor2 = db.BrandScoreHistoryUpdateFinal.find(
        {"UserOid" :ObjectId("55d6e7c0f0639509b4c7a83b")}).count()
```

It should return the count of userid for that particular value but its poping out the error as

> Name Error: name objectid is not defined.

when I tried to use  :

```
ObjectId("55d6e7c0f0639509b4c7a83b").toString()
cursor2 = db.BrandScoreHistoryUpdateFinal.find(
        {"UserOid" :ObjectId("55d6e7c0f0639509b4c7a83b")}).count()
```

I have the same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [search by ObjectId in mongodb with pymongo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073865/search-by-objectid-in-mongodb-with-pymongo)

Answer (score 0):

To query your document you need to import [**`ObjectId`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html)

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
```

Also the best way to do this is:

```
ursor2 = db.BrandScoreHistoryUpdateFinal.count(
        {"UserOid": ObjectId("55d6e7c0f0639509b4c7a83b")})
```