# $match(aggregation) fails with ObjectId values

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a simple collection.

```
> db.y.find({}, {'_id': 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf65") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf66") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf67") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf68") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf69") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf6a") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf6b") }
```

I want to operate a simple aggregation pipeline (*largely simplified for the explanation*)

I run this Mongo shell script:

```
print('find')
result = db.y.find({ '_id': ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64") }, {'_id':1})
while ( result.hasNext() ) { printjson( result.next() ); }

print('aggregate match direct')
result = db.y.aggregate( [ {'$match': {'_id': ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64") } }, {'$project': {'_id': 1}} ] )
while ( result.hasNext() ) { printjson( result.next() ); }

print('aggregate match with $eq')
result = db.y.aggregate( [ {'$match': {'_id': {'$eq': ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64") } } }, {'$project': {'_id': 1}} ] )
while ( result.hasNext() ) { printjson( result.next() ); }

print('aggregate match with $ne')
result = db.y.aggregate( [ {'$match': {'_id': {'$ne': ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64") } } }, {'$project': {'_id': 1}}, {'$limit': 5} ] )
while ( result.hasNext() ) { printjson( result.next() ); }
```

with this result (which is absolutely correct)

```
find
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64") }
aggregate match direct
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64") }
aggregate match with $eq
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64") }
aggregate match with $ne
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf65") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf66") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf67") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf68") }
```

Then I want to convert this to python as follows:

```
...
print('find')

result = y.find({ '_id': 'ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64")' }, {'_id':1})

for i, o in enumerate(result):
    print(i, o)

print('aggregate match direct')

result = y.aggregate( [ {'$match': {'_id': 'ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64")' } }, {'$project': {'_id': 1} } ] )

for i, o in enumerate(result):
    print(i, o)

print('aggregate match with $eq')

result = y.aggregate( [ {'$match': {'_id': {'$eq': 'ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64")' } } }, {'$project': {'_id': 1} } ] )

for i, o in enumerate(result):
    print(i, o)

print('aggregate match with $ne')

result = y.aggregate( [ {'$match': {'_id': {'$ne': 'ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64")' } } }, {'$project': {'_id': 1} }, {'$limit': 5} ] )

for i, o in enumerate(result):
    print(i, o)
```

with this result:

```
find
aggregate match direct
aggregate match with $eq
aggregate match with $ne
0 {'_id': ObjectId('5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64')}
1 {'_id': ObjectId('5908e63cd15fa104356eaf65')}
2 {'_id': ObjectId('5908e63cd15fa104356eaf66')}
3 {'_id': ObjectId('5908e63cd15fa104356eaf67')}
4 {'_id': ObjectId('5908e63cd15fa104356eaf68')}
```

Conclusion:

The $match operations never take the ObjectId syntax into account.

How to write it properly ??

Thanks for any hint

Christian

Comment: You are using PyMongo correct? `Y` is a cursor object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the ObjectId class in the standard library

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
result = y.find({ '_id': ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64") }, {'_id':1})
```

[Possibly Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073865/search-by-objectid-in-mongodb-with-pymongo)

Right now the match and find fields are asking if the _id is a string named "ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64)". But in Python, you have to assign a unique identifier first with the [ObjectId Class](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html)

Your last match is actually printing everything because you are asking if all _ids are not equal to the string "ObjectId("5908e63cd15fa104356eaf64)", not the ObjectId

Comment: But now I have a slightly different use case :